# How do i make my Check boxes preselected?

Tags: php, html

Okay, I am trying to create an invoice. The orders have already been made, and i have made it so that when you click "create invoice" it pulls those orders from the database. However, I need them all to be automatically selected when i click "create invoice" so that when the next screen pulls up with the orders listed, the checkboxes next to them are already checked and i dont have to click "check all"? Does that make sense? Im not allowed to post code but any help would be great. Also, I have tried simply to say checked = "checked" where the button is created but that isnt working.

Comment: How do you create your checkboxes? `<input type=checkbox checked>` is ok.

Comment: Not showing the code forces us to do the bad way of programming - guessing what's the issue and adding random things hoping it will work. Usually those kinds of issues can be caused by numerous things and they can be fixed in different ways and if you don't show us the code, we won't know what's the best solution. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: And how is the value of the checked box stored in the db?  If you have tried   `<input type="checkbox" name="something" checked="checked">` and that doesn't work then you have bigger problems.